# PCIe SSD - how reliable it is?

Tags: ssd, pci-express

Since The database will be very read/write intensive, and there is alot of delete queries which will be executed :

- How reliable could be PCIe SSD , and how fast will it degrade on alot of delete queries ?
  ( about a few hundred delete queries per second ).

Answer (score 2):

Certainly write-wearing remains a problem with any form of flash but things have improved a great deal over the last five years or so. The key is buy either buy a flash device with a good chunk of 'over-commit' space (storage set-aside to deal with parts of memory 'killed' by writes) - consumers SSDs typically have anywhere between zero and 7% of their space for this while high-end disks often seen this very much higher, sometimes more than 100%. Depending on a number of factors such as OS, filesystem and make/model of flash this setting may be tunable yourself and certainly setting aside, via product selection or manually, around 28% or so should pretty much ensure your flash will survive at least 3 years based on even quite heavy loads.

There is something else to consider, try really hard to pick an OS and filesystem combination that supports TRIM, this will only help a little with write-wearing but should improve and maintain overall performance with whichever flash based disk you go for.